# What preprocessing techniques work well for autoencoding audio?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders, data-preprocessing

I am wondering what preprocessing techniques work well for autoencoding audio data?

Specifically I have a dataset of ~0.5 second audio samples of people pronouncing digits 0-9 (think an audio version of MNIST). I would like to encoding them using an autoencoder and then use those encodings for classification using something similar to k-NN.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common representations of audio for speech recognition is MFCC: [Mel-frequency cepstrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum). It is a type of spectrogram, using Mel-spaced filter banks to approximate human hearing sensitivity dependency on frequency, and with correlation between bands removed using Discrete Cosine Transform.
Some machine learning approaches also uses the Mel-frequency spectrograms directly, without the de-correlation step. One of these should be a good starting point.

A common pre-processing step is to remove the mean (or median) of the spectrogram from all the bands. It is also common to remove frequencies outside the typical speech range using bandpass filters. Sometimes a pre-emphasis filter is applied to increase power of higher frequencies.